# Prove that the equation has infinitely many solutions in $\mathbb{N^{2}}: (x+1)^{2}+(x-1)^{2}=1+y^{2}$

Tags: number-theory

Prove that the equation has infinitely many solutions in $\mathbb{N^{2}} $:

> $$(x+1)^{2}+(x-1)^{2}=1+y^{2}$$

Note that (use this) :

> $$(3x+2y-1)^{2}+(3x+2y+1)^{2}=(4x+3y)^{2}+1$$

For all $x,y\in\mathbb{N}$

I don't know here? How do I use the hint?

My attempt was to put $z=3x+2y$ and $t=4x+3y$.

So I think the equation has infinitely many solutions?

Comment: $y^2-2x^2=1$ is a [Pell equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation)

Comment: I mean, isn't $y^2-2x=1$ the condition on $x$ and $y$?

Answer (score 2):

Note that the original equation is equivalent to $y^2-2x^2=1$.

If we have a solution $(x,y)=(m,n)$ to $y^2-2x^2=\pm1$ then it is easy to check that $(M,N)=(3m+2n,4m+3n)$ is a solution to $y^2-2x^2=\mp1$.

So given a solution $(m,n)$ to the original equation, $(3M+2N,4M+3N)$ is a larger solution. Hence there are infinitely many.

Comment: Thank you sir @almagest nice...+1!

Answer (score 1):

As @Dietrich_Burde has already pointed out, you have a family of solutions to your original equation. Written out explicitly, note that $(x,y)=(0,1)$ satisfies your equation as

$$(0+1)^2+(0-1)^2=1+1=2$$

$$1+1^2=1+1=2$$

Now, let us define a sequence of points, each of which will be a solution to the equation:

$$(a_1,b_1)=(0,1)$$

$$(a_{n+1},b_{n+1})=(3a_n+2b_n,4a_n+3b_n)$$

We will proceed by induction. Obviously, for $n=1$ the point $(a_1,b_1)$ satisfies the equation. Now, $(a_n,b_n)$ satisfies the equation for $n\geq 1$. Then we have

$$(a_{n+1}+1)^2+(a_{n+1}-1)^2-(b_{n+1}^2-1)=2a_n^2+1-b_n^2$$

However from our inductive hypothesis we know

$$0=(a_n+1)^2+(a_n-1)^2-(b_n^2+1)=2a_n^2+1-b_n^2$$

Thus, $(a_{n+1},b_{n+1})$ satisfy the equations and we are done.

Comment: Thanks! @QC_QAOA nice work!

Answer (score 1):

The wording in the question was unfortunate. They were describing the "automorphism group" of the indefinite binary form $x^2 - 2 y^2.$

A fair amount of explanation is needed, however, if
$$ (x_{n+1}, y_{n+1}) = (3 x_n + 4 y_n , 2 x_n + 3 y_n), $$
THEN
$$ \color{red}{ x_{n+1}^2 - 2 y_{n+1}^2 = x_n^2 - 2 y_n^2} $$

In the specified case, $x^2 - 2 y^2 = 1,$ this leads to solutions  in a sequence with
$$ x_{n+2} = 6 x_{n+1} - x_n \; , \;  $$
$$ y_{n+2} = 6 y_{n+1} - y_n \; , \;  $$
beginning with $(1,0) \;, \; \; $ $(3,2) \;, \; \; $ $(17,12) \;, \; \; $  $(99,70) \;, \; \; $

[image]

Comment: Very nice way! Thanks!